# Are there any JSP File for manage PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, jsp

1.
I need jsp file to manage PostgreSQL database?!
Anyone know JSP file for manage PostgreSQL database?!

2.
How I can connect to remote PostgreSQL Server with Webmin?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use JDBC to connect to a database from JSP
2. Refer to the official [webmin docs](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/PostgreSQLDatabaseServer#The_PostgreSQL_Database_Server_m)

Comment: Do you know any single JSP file for manage PostgreSQL?!

Comment: What do you mean with "single file", you just import JDBC and write your own class.